# What is the way to update info.plist with the URL Scheme when using branch.io?

Tags: url-scheme, branch.io, info.plist

I am reading conflicting information so unsure what to do.

According to this document: https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#2-configure-associated-domains

I need to submit a URL Scheme.  Recommendations?  Apple says reverse DNS.

According to this document: https://branch.io/glossary/uri-schemes/

URL Schemes are obsolete.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

*A Branchster here -*

While most of the redirection happens through Universal Links on iOS there can be certain situations where a third-party app is not able to trigger UL and in that case, the fallback redirection using URI schemes comes into the picture.

Ideally, you should set up both Universal Links and URI schemes in your `Info.plist` file so that you cover all the edge cases. You can check out the recommendations for the URI scheme [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app) though just ensure it is something unique to your app.

To start you need to configure your Branch Dashboard enabling Universal Links toggle and entering your URI scheme and app information -
[image: Branch Dashboard]

You can then proceed to enter the same information in your project's `Info.plist` file -

```
<key>branch_universal_link_domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>sample.app.link</string>
        <string>sample-alternate.app.link</string>
        <string>sample.test.app.link</string>
        <string>sample-alternate.test.app.link</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.your.schene</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.branch.monster</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>branch_key</key>
    <dict>
        <key>live</key>
        <string>key_live_</string>
        <key>test</key>
        <string>key_test_</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Thanks @kartik -- I went through and updated this and it looked like this...except I read that we cannot have both a live and test key so I didn't include it.  I made the changes via xcode.  

But I'm still not able to get it to compile and deploy in a way to test it.